Error while upgrading Springboot microservice from 2.x to 3.x - classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes
While trying to upgrade Springboot from 2.7.18 to 3.0.0 (along with Java 17), I'm getting the following error at runtime while starting the application.  Build is successful though.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
- io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.messaging.SnsAutoConfiguration
- io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration
Reviewed the 'auto-configuration' section in the below migration guide but couldn't find anythign to be changed in the existing codebase relevant to this.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide
If anyone has any clue, please keep me posted.
Thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you upgrade Spring cloud accordingly?

As you are using Spring Cloud you cannot just upgrade Spring Boot you also must upgrade Spring Cloud to a compatible version. Else it won't work. I suspect you only upgraded Spring Boot and not Spring Cloud.

Thank you for your responses.  Upon further analysis, i noticed that javax.validation was existing in the pom file.  I've replaced as follows and the issue is resolved.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

